# Correctly way to declare var with another var PHP

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I need a way to declare a variable to use in `while` loop like this:

```
$x = 1;
    while ($x < 5){
    echo $row['img$x'];
    $x++;
}
```

In my case, this returned a syntax error.

Comment: basic php 101: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables. you have a literal `$` and `x` in your array key name.

Comment: So simple, Thanks! haha

Comment: There's no syntax error there.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, it's somewhere else. Your code is wrong, but it's valid PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

```
$row['img' . $x]
// or
$row["img$x"]
```

Use double quotes `""` if you want to use string interpolation and `.` for string concatenation.